# How to show the post title in dynamic url routing

Tags: django

i am currently working on a web application project in django ,I want to display the post title in dynamic url routing in post detail page

Now my url is like localhost/blog/detail/1 '1 is post id'
i want to add the post title in the above url with dynamic url routing
like
localhost/blog/detail/name of the instance post/id

views.py

```
def blog_detail(request,id=None):
    instance=get_object_or_404(blogPost,id=id)
    args={"instance":instance}
    return render(request,'blog/blogDetail.html',args)
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
url(r'^$',views.blog,name="blog"),
url(r'^details/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$',views.blog_detail,name="details"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class blogPost(models.Model):
    postTitle=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postContent=models.TextField(blank=False,default="Not found")
    category=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.postTitle

    def __str__(self):
        return self.postTitle

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details',kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in babak's answer, you probably want to use a slugfield. If you want the slugfield to be automatically populated based on the title's value, you need to override your model's `save` method (this is because the slugfield's value must be set after the `title` field's value is already known). Also, you'd probably want to change the model's `get_absolute_url` method. You could for instance do this:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify #new


class BlogPost(models.Model): #changed
    postTitle=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postContent=models.TextField(blank=False,default="Not found")
    category=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField() # new

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.postTitle

    def __str__(self):
        return self.postTitle

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details',kwargs={"id":self.id, "slug":self.slug}) #changed

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # new
        self.slug = slugify(self.postTitle)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

(note that I renamed the model from `blogPost` to `BlogPost`, in line with Python naming conventions for classes)

You'll need to change the urls.py file too, so that it will work with the modified model. Here's a suggestion (using the `path` function instead of the `url` function you used in your code):

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path #changed
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('details/<slug:slug>/<int:id>/',views.blog_detail,name="details"), #changed
]
```

If you do use this approach, note that you need to change your view too, so that it accepts a 'slug' argument (though the view doesn't really have to do anything with the slug variable):

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import BlogPost #changed

def blog_detail(request, slug, id=None): #changed
    instance=get_object_or_404(BlogPost,id=id)
    args={"instance":instance}
    return render(request,'blog/blogDetail.html',args)
```

Here's a couple of tests I wrote to check that the model and the view are functioning as expected. I'm including them here in case they might help clarify the behavior/what's going on.

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import BlogPost

class ModelsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.bp1 = BlogPost.objects.create(postTitle='First post',
                                           postContent='This is a post',
                                           category='Fun category',
                                           author='First author')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_blogpost_slug(self):
        bp = BlogPost.objects.get(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(bp.slug, 'first-post')

    def test_blogpost_url(self):
        bp = BlogPost.objects.get(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(bp.get_absolute_url(), '/blog/details/first-post/1/')


class ViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.bp1 = BlogPost.objects.create(postTitle='First post',
                                           postContent='This is a post',
                                           category='Fun category',
                                           author='First author')
        self.client = Client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_blog_detail_view_responds_with_status_code_200(self):
        firstpost_url = self.bp1.get_absolute_url()
        resp = self.client.get(firstpost_url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

All three tests run successfully.

There ought, of course, to be a more elegant solution when it comes to the url patterns, that doesn't involve passing the unnecessary 'slug' argument to the view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not do this because it's not standard (it may be two or more blog detail with same title)

if you want to use this anyway you should use slugField because title may have space character which is forbidden in web urls.

for doing this you need a slugField in your models which is connected to your title
and you need to change your route in urls.py something like this:

```
url('details/<slug:title>',views.blog_detail,name="details")
```

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem if there were two posts that have the same title. The reason is that OP said they want a url in the format 'localhost/blog/detail/1', i. e. there will always be a unique ID at the end. So if I understand OP correctly, instead of just `'details/<slug:title>'`, the pattern would be something like `'details/<slug:title>/<int:id>/'`